# Getting the error "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle"

Tags: java, spring

Checked similar threads with the same errors, but still unable to find where is the cause of the error.  I am following tutorial and trying to create simple login page with username and password using spring, as well as implementing two roles of user.

Here is my securityConfig file and my userServiceImplement file which are causing this error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ws").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users").hasAnyAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name())
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login-error")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}`



    @Service
public class UserServiceImplement implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImplement(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(UserDTO userDto) {
        if(!Objects.equals(userDto.getPassword(), userDto.getMatchingPassword())){
            throw new RuntimeException("Password is not equal");
        }
        User user = User.builder()
                .name(userDto.getUsername())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()))
                .email(userDto.getEmail())
                .role(Role.USER)
                .build();
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findFirstByName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User was not found with this name" + username);

        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getName(),
                user.getPassword(),
                roles
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `SecurityConfig` provides a `PasswordEncoder` and requires a `UserService`. Class `UserServiceImplement` is a `UserService` and requires a `PasswordEncoder`. In other words, to create a `SecurityConfig` you need a `UserService`, but to create a `UserService` you need a `SecurityConfig` to provide the `PasswordEncoder`.

The easiest fix is probably to move the `PasswordEncoder` method outside of `SecurityConfig`.
An alternative is to treat `UserServiceImplement` as a POJO (remove the `@Service` annotation) and create it manually inside the `authenticationProvider` method. You'll need a `UserRepository` for that, but you can use method argument injection for that:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserRepository userRepository) {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder();
    UserService userService = new UserServiceImplement(userRepository, passwordEncoder);

    DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return auth;
}
```